# Don't show again checkbox for form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dialog

I am wondering how to implement I would implement a "Dont show again" checkbox, that when checked and the form is closed, it wont show again on startup. Do I need to store it in the registry? Or a config file maybe that on application startup it checks for the boolean value? I am just wondering the best approach. I am using vb.net.

Comment: Is there some sort of membership schema?  It would be easy enough to save a boolean value and check that upon login/however this process works.

Comment: No membership, although it will usually only be one person per account using the software, so I think just on the main form load will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used MS Access database for this, I deploy mdf file with the exe, but yes you can use Registry as well, when you use "Settings" Section within VB to save values, it creates an entry into Registry.

Comment: ahhh, I never thought of my.settings. Thanks.

Comment: If this worked for you, mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark to the left for future users that view this question.